# How to create tar.gz archive file in Windows?

Tags: windows, gzip, cpanel, tar, 7zip

How to create tar.gz archive of my files in Windows to upload and extract in cPanel?

Comment: Use 7-zip?  http://www.7-zip.org/

Comment: first you compress it to tar with 7-zip and then to gzip with 7-zip

Comment: You can easily do this with "Bash on Ubuntu on Windows" using `cd /mnt/c/[path to folder to archive]` and then `tar -pczf archive.tar.gz *`

Comment: In Windows 10 you can use tar natively https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27316046/unzip-tar-gz-in-windows

Answer (score 91, accepted):

tar.gz file is just a tar file that's been gzipped. Both **tar** and **gzip** are available for windows.

If you like GUIs (Graphical user interface), [7zip](http://www.7-zip.org/) can pack with both tar and gzip.

Comment: the problem is that it cannot compress to .tar.gz in one go

Comment: In case it isn't clear, in 7zip you must first create the tar; it won't even show the option for Gzip if multiple files (or a folder) are selected. Reference: http://www.random-host.com/blog/creating-targz-file-7-zip

Comment: Can you please show how to do this on the command line?

Comment: @ChristopherPisz I would be useful if I could answer and explain that but question is locked, plz vote for reopen