# Unzip tar.gz in Windows

Tags: batch-file, tar

I would like to unzip Filename.tar.gz to Filename using single command in windows batch script
All the files inside zip should go inside the Filename Folder
I am trying to do in windows . I am not getting correct output.
Can anyone suggest an idea

Comment: try 7zip, http://superuser.com/questions/80019/how-can-i-unzip-a-tar-gz-in-one-step-using-7-zip

Comment: This doesnt work properly

Answer (score 6, accepted):

7 zip can do that: http://www.7-zip.org/

It has a documented command line. I use it every day via scripts.

Plus: it is free and has 32 and 64 bit versions.

Comment: You are right, sorry. The best documentation is in the help installed by installer. Then you can find a good support in forum.

Answer (score 27):

Windows Command line now supports tar from Windows 10 insider build 17063. You may try run the below command in cmd or PowerShell to see if it works:

```
tar -xzvf your-file-name.tar.gz
```

Comment: `tar -xvzf C:\PATH\TO\FILE\FILE-NAME.tar.gz -C C:\PATH\TO\FOLDER\EXTRACTION` is the full syntax , you seem to omit/typo the dash in front of a parameter

Comment: For those that don't know what the parameters mean: `x` means extract, `z` means gzip and that the file is `.tar.gz` or `.tgz`, `v` means verbose, `f` means the next argument is the filename.

Answer (score 3):

## Windows 10 command line supports tar command

Write the tar command as general to the Linux terminal.

`tar -zxvf tar-filename.tar.gz --directory destination-folder`

Answer (score 0):

Another option is the Arc program:

```
arc unarchive test.tar.gz
```

https://github.com/mholt/archiver

Answer (score 0):

in windows compand promt use quotation marks ("") when specifying the path. It will work properly

Exaple : tar -xvzf "C:/PATH/TO/FILE/FILE-NAME.tar.gz" -C "C:/PATH/TO/FOLDER/EXTRACTION"

tar -xvzf "C:/PATH/TO/FILE/FILE-NAME.tar.gz"